# How to get data from a spesific youtube playlist just the titles and the descriptions and show them in a recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin

How to get data from a specific YouTube playlist just the titles and the descriptions and show them in a RecyclerView and when the user clicks on a item it leads them to that YouTube video, I have no idea how can I do that if you have any useful resources please provide me with them

all the codes I've wrote none of them has been worked

Comment: Can you post an example of what you've tried to help us guide you?

Comment: i've uploaded my project on github : https://github.com/MohamedMBG/YTB_Features